# Correct way to delete a Binary tree node

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have this problem, when i try to delete(using choice 5) the node with id 101 and want to print remaining two nodes(with ids 100,102). My program prints(using choice 2) 100 correctly but for the rest it produce some garbage value and program stop working ?

I suspect some memory management issue, Can someone please make proper way to do it.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;
struct bin_tree
{
    int Uid;
    int data;
    bool flag_add;
    bool flag_change;
    bool flag_delete;
    struct bin_tree * right, * left;

};
typedef struct bin_tree node;

void insert(node ** tree,int ID, int val,bool new_data, bool change_data, bool delete_data)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = new node;
        temp->left =  NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->Uid=ID;
        temp->data = val;
        temp->flag_add= new_data;
        temp->flag_change=change_data;
        temp->flag_delete=delete_data;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }else
    {

        if(val < (*tree)->data)
        {
            insert(&(*tree)->left, ID, val,new_data, change_data, delete_data);
        }
        else
        {
            insert(&(*tree)->right,ID, val,new_data, change_data, delete_data);
        }
    }
}

void print_preorder(node * tree, int indent=0)
{

    cout<<"GUID"<<tree->Uid <<"D"<< tree->data <<"NF"<<tree->flag_add<<"CF"<<tree->flag_change<<"DF"<<tree->flag_delete<< "\n ";


    if (tree!= NULL)
    {
        if(tree->left) print_preorder(tree->left, indent+2);

        if(tree->right) print_preorder(tree->right, indent+2);

        if (indent)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(indent) << ' ';
        }

    }
}





node* search(node ** tree, int ID)
{
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(ID < (*tree)->Uid)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->left), ID);
    }
    else if(ID > (*tree)->Uid)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->right), ID);
    }
    else if(ID == (*tree)->Uid)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
}
node*  update(node ** tree,int ID, int val,bool new_data, bool change_data, bool delete_data)
{
    (*tree)->Uid = ID;
    (*tree)->data = val;
    (*tree)->flag_add= new_data;
    (*tree)->flag_change= change_data;
    (*tree)->flag_delete= delete_data;

    return *tree;


}


void change(node ** tree,int ID, int val,bool new_data, bool change_data, bool delete_data)
{

    node *temp;
    node* updt;

    temp = search(&(*tree), ID);

    if(temp)
    {
        cout<<"ID is found"<<endl;
        cout<<"Node current data is "<<temp->Uid<<temp->data<<temp->flag_add<<temp->flag_change<<temp->flag_delete<<endl;
        if(updt = update(&temp,ID, val, new_data, change_data, delete_data))
        {
            cout<<"Node updated data is "<<updt->Uid<<updt->data<<updt->flag_add<<updt->flag_change<<updt->flag_delete;
        }else
        {
            cout<<"data couldnt be updated"<<endl;
        }
    }else
    {
        cout<<"sorry data is not found"<<endl;

    }


}

int deltree(node ** tree, int id)
{
    node *del_node;
    del_node= search( &(*tree), id);
    if(del_node)
    {
        delete del_node;

    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    node *root;
    node *tmp;
    int number;
    int id;



    root = NULL;
    int UID;
    int Data;
    bool n_flag;
    bool c_flag;
    bool d_flag;
    /* Inserting nodes into tree */

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<" Binary Search Tree Operations "<<endl;
        cout<<" ----------------------------- "<<endl;
        cout<<" 1. Insertion/Creation "<<endl;
        cout<<" 2. Pre-Order Traversal "<<endl;
        cout<<" 3. Removal "<<endl;// actually its for searching not for removal
        cout<<" 4. change "<<endl;
        cout<<" 5. delete "<<endl;
        cout<<" 6. EXIT "<<endl;

        cout<<" Enter your choice : ";
        cin>>number;
        switch(number)
        {
        case 1:

            /*cout<<"enter the number GUID"<<endl;
            cin>>UID;
            cout<<"enter the Data you want"<<endl;
            cin>>Data;
            cout<<"is New data ?"<<endl;
            cin>>n_flag;
            cout<<"is changed data?"<<endl;
            cin>>c_flag;
            cout<<"is delete data ?"<<endl;
            cin>>d_flag;*/

            /*  insert(&root,UID, Data, n_flag, c_flag,d_flag);*/

            insert(&root,100, 700, 1, 0,0);
            insert(&root,101, 701, 1, 0,0);
            insert(&root,102, 702, 1, 0,0);
            break;

        case 2:
            /* Printing nodes of tree */
            cout<<"Pre Order tree Display";
            print_preorder(root);
            break;

        case 3:

            /* Search node into tree */
            tmp = search(&root, 4);
            if (tmp)
            {
                printf("Searched node=%d\n", tmp->data);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Data Not found in tree.\n");
            }
            break;
        case 4:

            cout<<"enter the number GUID"<<endl;
            cin>>UID;
            cout<<"enter the Data you want"<<endl;
            cin>>Data;
            cout<<"is New data ?"<<endl;
            cin>>n_flag;
            cout<<"is changed data?"<<endl;
            cin>>c_flag;
            cout<<"is delete data ?"<<endl;
            cin>>d_flag;

            change (&root,UID, Data, n_flag, c_flag,d_flag);

            break;
        case 5:
            cout<<"enter the node id to be deleted";
            cin>>id;
            int m;
            m = deltree(&root, id);
            if(m) cout<<"Node_Deleted";
            break;
        case 6 :
            return 0;

        }

    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Can you please have a look at output !

Answer (score 2):

When deleting a node in a tree, you have to properly manage its children. Here you are deleting the node and the pointers to its children along with it. You need to find a way to add the remaining children back into the tree.

Answer (score 2):

When you use delete operator, the memory allocated for that object (node in this case) is being freed. 
In function deleteTree you find the node and dealocate it's memory, but the **pointer to that node** (from its parent node) **isn't being reset to NULL**, **it "hangs"** pointing to something other then NULL. So after when u use recursion to print tree, you print root, you check left tree (it's not NULL) and u call recursion for printing something that doesnt make sense, and you continue with the recursion who knows how many times.

Also, when you **delete a subtree**, you should use recursion to **delete all the nodes in that tree**, not just the root of the tree (and as above, set the pointer to that subtree to NULL), thus freeing the whole memory reserved for that subtree.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, deleting a node in your tree may lead to a memory leak.
For instance if you have this tree:
A->B
A->C
and you delete A, the references to B and C are lost.

You my can either use valgrind (linux) or purify (windows) to check it.

One way to fix it would be to implement a destructor to your structure:
The recursion will be automatically handled.

```
struct bin_tree
{
    int Uid;
    int data;
    bool flag_add;
    bool flag_change;
    bool flag_delete;
    struct bin_tree * right, * left;

    bin_tree() : right(nullptr), left(nullptr) {}
    ~bin_tree()
    {
        delete right;
        delete left;
    }
}
```

NB do not forget the null pointer on initialisation.
In addition, if you want to use a binary tree in real life, do not forget that std::map is a binary tree.

Have a good day